# Running multiple command lines in parallel and printing back outputs (Python/cmd)

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I couldnt find any answer to this. 
One of the command lines is a call to an exe that its return value isn't relevant.
On the other hand, the output of the code is important to me.
I need to run this exe in parallel to another bat file I wrote, but I can't find a way to get the output and run it in parallel as well.
Is there a way in python/cmd to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In batch files, you could use `start XYZ` to run stuff without blocking on it.  If you want to use python for it (which I advise over batch), use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["my.exe", "arg1", "arg2"])
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "my.bat"])

p1.wait()
p2.wait()
```

Comment: Amazing. Works well. Thank you!

Comment: what does; the `start` or the `subprocess`?

Comment: You can run a .bat or .cmd file directly. WinAPI `CreateProcess` executes it via the `%ComSpec%` shell, if defined, and defaults to cmd.exe otherwise. Also, the `subprocess.Popen` equivalent of CMD's `start` command also requires `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`. Your current example is more like `start /b`.

Comment: Thanks, @eryksun, I believe that OP indeed has enough with a console-less process.

Comment: If the Python script isn't running via pythonw.exe (non-console), then as you've written it, if "my.exe" is a console process, it will interfere with the cmd.exe process that's running the batch script. Code defensively to launch my.exe as a parallel process in a separate console, which could be created with a hidden window (via `STARTUPINFO`) or without a window (`CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag). These parameters are harmless if "my.exe" isn't a console process. Then let Windows default to `%ComSpec%` to run the batch, i.e. `subprocess.Popen(['my.bat'])`.